# AWS HTTP Gateway: private integration routing without path variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-api-gateway

I've been setting up an HTTP gateway for the first time and came across an issue with private integrations. I want all my integrations to be private but it doesn't work well with routing.

I have a private integration with a `$default` route and it works great.
Now I want another private integration to be mounted under, say, `/microservice/` and have all its endpoints proxied.

This however seems impossible because private integrations ask you for a backend ARN rather than URI, so there's no way to use path variables like `{proxy+}`. This results in only root of my microservice being accessible through the gateway - all the other paths just go to the `$default` route.

How would one go about setting up a private integration like this? Ideally I would like something like this:

```
- /microservice1/{proxy+}
- /microservice2/{proxy+}
- $default
```

Currently as I understand it I only have two options:

- Expose my services to the world and use public integration with greedy path variables `{proxy+}` - not ideal
- Keep the private integration but define each microservice endpoint as it's own route on the gateway - extremely annoying to maintain

Is there a good way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question - this is possible with [request parameter mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-parameter-mapping.html) that transforms request before it reaches the backend:

1. Create a route with greedy path variable: `/microservice/${proxy}`
2. In your private integration create a path mapping: `overwrite:path = /$request.path.proxy`

Comment: @dmitrybelyajov, do you know how to implement path rewrite like this:

api.example.com/v1/app1/user/add => https://app1.example.com/user/add

I.e. without "/v1/app1" part.


https://repost.aws/questions/QU8_a_LKzJT86VCIV4-J3cpA/api-http-gateway-path-rewrite-question